# Web API URL from a asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a hyperlink in a Web Forms project and it's href is set to a web api call.

http://www.domain1.com/form.aspx has

```
<a href="http://www.domain2.com/somewhere/houston" target="_blank">Test</a>
```

"houston" is the parameter.
I get a 404 error when I click on the link. When I debug my Web API 2 application using the link above, everything works fine. But the Web forms application cannot seem to find it. I have also tried:

```
<a href="http://www.domain2.com/somewhere?id=houston">Test</a>
```

I have even tried:

```
<a href="http://www.domain2.com/somewhere.aspx?id=houston">Test</a>
```

My project on "domain2" is in MVC Web API 2. What am I doing wrong? I'm missing something.

I'm not getting any data back in return or waiting for any event. It simply opens in a new tab and only needs the parameter and returns nothing back to the calling page. Is it a routing issue? TIA!

Comment: what does your webapi method look like (with parameters)?

Comment: This is not about webforms app, this is about your web api. Does your routing understand "somewhere/houston"? Default route will send this to controller "Somewhere", action "Houston", do you have that? Alternatively do you have special route for this url?

Comment: Is your Web API method marked with `[HttpPost]`. Do note a hyperlink will send a GET, not a POST or other verb.

Comment: It's marked with a GET. As for routing, why would it work in localhost when I debug and not otherwise.

Comment: @Andrei thanks for pointing me to the routes. The path was wrong. Most of my calls were 2 levels down. But this particular call was at the same level. Took out the ../../ and added the controller and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Not resolved yet. Routes work fine in localhost. But not when called from an external site. 404 error. If I change the route to include the controller specifically as you mentioned, it jumps to the wrong controller.The controller it's jumping to has a template {a}/{b}/{c} - these are parameters. The controller I want it to go to comes in this form: /Controller/Action/{parameter}. So, it's confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the route worked fine. The compiled dll was missing from the server, which is why it worked locally but when called from another website, the 404 error popped up. Once I copied the dll to the right folder on the server, everything worked fine.